# What is the grooviest way to do a null check on Sql's firstRow?

Tags: groovy

I am using Groovy's SQL class to retrieve a value through a simple query like so...

```
 def catName = mySql.firstRow("select name from cat where cat_id = ${cid}").name
```

Problem is if no value is found for a given cat id then this throws a null pointer exception. So what is the grooviest way to do this null check (using the fewest lines of code possible)?

Comment: `mySql.firstRow("select name from cat where cat_id = ${cid}")?.name` notice `?.` is the null safe operator.

Comment: Did u try  def catName = mySql.firsRow("select name from cat where cat_id = ${cid}")?.name

Comment: @user3223841 when asking questions, can you please post the error if you are getting one?  Just naming the exception isn't good enough for accurate answers

Comment: as other comments the way to do it is using `?` safe navigation operator... only to add more info check out the documentation: url: http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator

Comment: @tim_yates, I was getting a null pointer exception (java.lang.NullPointerException). I believe I mentioned that in the post.

Comment: Yes, but a stacktrace (or the top of the stacktrace) tells you where.  Like telling a doctor "my body hurts" rather than telling them which part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of good Q&A, here's @dmahapatro comment, which is a perfectly correct answer:

`mySql.firstRow("select name from cat where cat_id = ${cid}")?.name`

Notice `?.` - it is [the null safe operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator).